# stream >> reading last line twice

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, eof

I am trying to parse `/proc/partitions` file.

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1   99998720 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        3  103561216 sda3
   8        4  291514368 sda4
   8        5    1998848 sda5
```

This is the /proc/partitions file in my machine.

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main(){
  std::ifstream proc_partitions_stream("/proc/partitions");
  boost::int32_t disc_partition_line_count = -2; //-1 for headers, -1 for the empty line
  //so counter is 0 when it tries to read the real entries
  while(!proc_partitions_stream.fail()){
    if(disc_partition_line_count >= 0){
      boost::uint16_t   major, minor;
      boost::uint64_t   blocks;
      std::string   label;
      proc_partitions_stream >> major >> minor >> blocks >> label;
      std::cout << boost::format("%1% %2% %3% %4%") % major % minor % blocks % label << std::endl;
      boost::algorithm::trim(label);      
    }else{
      std::string line;
      std::getline(proc_partitions_stream, line);
    }
    ++disc_partition_line_count;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

But it reads **the last line twice**  Here is the program

```
8 0 976762584 [sda]
8 1 99998720 [sda1]
8 2 1 [sda2]
8 3 103561216 [sda3]
8 4 291514368 [sda4]
8 5 1998848 [sda5]
8 5 1998848 [] << read the last line TWICE but didn't read the label
```

Comment: You never check your input extractions for success. And you're loop is no better than checking for eof in a while-conditional, [which is almost *always* wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

Because your while loop condition is wrong, you test for failure **before** you read, you should test for failure **after** you read. Even better would be to test the return from `getline`.

Comment: But then I've to create a stringstream after getline and extract values or split by space. Should I check after every `stream >> v` operation ? and why would it read the line twice ? it should always go forward. But it is going backward to the beginning of last line.

Comment: @NeelBasu It's not reading twice. It just doesn't overwrite the variable values by the unsuccessful read. So you just *process* them twice. And you don't have to test every `>>`; testing the last one is sufficient.

Comment: Ya Thanks. I see now. If I initialize them to 0 its not filling them with previous value again.

Comment: I've tried checking after the last `>>` operation. I did put an `if(proc_partitions_stream.fail())break;` after `>> label` that gave same output

Comment: Try `if (!proc_partitions_stream) break;`. I believe `fail()` is specifically for failure to convert, you have end of file.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite it to something more like:

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main(){
  std::ifstream proc_partitions_stream("/proc/partitions");

  for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
      proc_partitions_stream.ignore(max_len, '\n');

  boost::uint16_t   major, minor;
  boost::uint64_t   blocks;
  std::string   label;
  while (proc_partitions_stream >> major >> minor >> blocks >> label) {
      std::cout << boost::format("%1% %2% %3% %4%") % major % minor % blocks % label << "\n";
      //boost::algorithm::trim(label); // was present, but non-functional?
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, define a small class to represent a disc partition, and overload operator>> and << for that, as well as a small function to skip lines from an istream:

```
class partition { 
    boost::uint16_t major, minor;
    boost uint64_t  blocks;
    std::string     label;
public:
     friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, partition &p) { 
         return is >> major >> minor >> blocks >> label;
     }

     friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, partition const &p) { 
         return os << boost::format("%1% %2% %3% %4%") % major % minor % blocks % label;
     }
};

std::istream &skiplines(std::istream &is, unsigned count) { 
   unsigned max_len = something; // see below
   return is.ignore(max_len, '\n');
}
```

Then in `main` you'd just have something like:

```
if (!skiplines(2)) {
    std::cerr << "Error!\n";
    return 1;
}

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<partition>(proc_partitions_stream),
          std::istream_iterator<partition>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<partition>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

As far as what value to use for `max_len` goes: quite a few people use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`. I prefer something quite a bit smaller as a rule. It probably doesn't make any difference in this case (chances or mis-formatted input are small) but if you're just trying to skip a line, it's better to limit it to some amount that's at least halfway reasonable for a line. If you're just going to tell the user there's a problem anyway, there's no reason to waste their time waiting for you to read gigabytes of garbage before you do so.